# linq query where some from values might be missing

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm pulling contacts from JSON, there are contacts inside Data that might contain emails and phone numbers.

If they do the following query works perfectly:

```
var results = from d in json.Data
                from c in d.Contacts
                from e in c.Emails
                from p in c.Phones
                select new IoModel {Email = e.EmailValue, Id = d.Id, FullName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Name) ? c.Name : d.DisplayName, Phone = p.PhoneNumber, DOB = d.CustomDOB};
```

If the Data doesn't have Emails or Phones then it runs with no error but it doesn't return the Contact Name.

Is there a way to do this without using if and and's to keep the code shorter and cleaner?

Here is an example of the JSON with a missing email:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "addresses": [], 
            "contacts": [
                {
                    "created_by": "user_ltUL3eXGPRWb5ghDeGTfOe9qjW0LeE2e4ouopLcSSWj", 
                    "date_created": "2017-12-28T17:13:00.392000+00:00", 
                    "date_updated": "2017-12-28T17:13:58.453000+00:00", 
                    "emails": [], 
                    "id": "cont_6hxxhz51ctlTnHfo8gA8cce0rthS1dJy1kguKAj148s", 
                    "integration_links": [
                        {
                            "name": "LinkedIn Search", 
                            "url": "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=John%20Doe"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "lead_id": "lead_3UzfxCgQHmw4BlGwElitHhlP6E7q9Tg3sdSkTl1CIXp", 
                    "name": "John Doe", 
                    "organization_id": "orga_PvgGx1opSZDsCHl73P8OoSFZUlJ3qsNGI2kwgoObM17", 
                    "phones": [
                        {
                            "phone": "+15555555555", 
                            "phone_formatted": "+1 555-555-5555", 
                            "type": "mobile"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "title": "Main Service", 
                    "updated_by": "user_ltUL3eXXPRWb5shDeGTfOe9qjP0LeE2e4ouopLcSSWj", 
                    "urls": []
                }
            ], 
            "created_by": "user_ltUL3eXXPRWb5shDeGTfOe9qjW0LeE2e4ouopLcSSWP", 
            "created_by_name": "John", 
            "custom": {
                "Date Of Birth": "1901-08-01", 
                "Department": "Main Service", 
                "Initial Service": "Main Service"
            }, 
            "custom.lcf_ufMH5ZhlR99zcdvJxKMxdgxcIbV4wtgTb3EdWDEkL8g": "1971-08-17", 
            "date_created": "2017-12-28T17:13:00.388000+00:00", 
            "date_updated": "2017-12-29T21:41:53.840000+00:00", 
            "description": "", 
            "display_name": "John Doe", 
            "html_url": "https://app.close.io/lead/lead_3UzfxCgQHmw4BlGwElitHhlP6E7q9Tg3sdSkTl1CIXp/", 
            "id": "lead_3UzfxCgQHmw4BlGwElitHhlP5E7q9Tg3sdSkTl1CIXp", 
            "integration_links": [
                {
                    "name": "Google Search", 
                    "url": "http://google.com/search?q=John%20Doe"
                }
            ], 
            "name": "", 
            "opportunities": [], 
            "organization_id": "orga_AvcGx4opSZDsCHl73H8OogDDUlJ3qsNGI2kwgoObA17", 
            "status_id": "stat_LpJu8FO72WgIob4qDDVnS4GEieoU41zmQ8xBquTvusm", 
            "status_label": "Established Patient", 
            "tasks": [], 
            "updated_by": "user_0JFRnl8QRvRhMhAlLz4JJxgmrzPeLs3xboxYyj5Pm80", 
            "updated_by_name": "BT", 
            "url": null
        }
    ], 
    "has_more": false, 
    "total_results": 1
}
```

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON to get the `json` variable?  (What type is it?)   Can you provide  a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know what you are deserializing your JSON into, I can only guess at a solution here, but I think if you use `DefaultIfEmpty()` on your `Emails` and `Phones` collections and then use the null-conditional operator on the `EmailValue` and `PhoneNumber`, you should get the result you want:

```
var results = from d in json.Data
              from c in d.Contacts
              from e in c.Emails.DefaultIfEmpty()
              from p in c.Phones.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new IoModel
              {
                  Email = e?.EmailValue,
                  Id = d.Id,
                  FullName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Name) ? c.Name : d.DisplayName,
                  Phone = p?.PhoneNumber,
                  DOB = d.CustomDOB
              };
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain the issue you are running into. Imagine the following two lists:

**Issue**

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var names = new List<string>();
```

Let's write a Linq query to get all the ids along with names:

```
var idsAndNames = from id in ids
                  from name in names
                  select new { Id = id, Name = name };
```

The above query will return no results. Why? This is more obvious if you were to use a `foreach` instead of Linq. The `foreach` version will look roughly like below:

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        //select new { Id = id, Name = name };
    }
}
```

It is very clear and obvious why no results will be returned in the `foreach` version above (the code within the inner loop will not be executed because the `names` list is empty).

**Fix**

We need to tell our query: *If there are no items in `names` collection, we will accept the default*. We can do that using `DefaultIfEmpty` method.

```
var idsAndNames = from id in ids
                  from name in names.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new { Id = id, Name = name };
```

The above will return 4 results. It is sort of like doing the following:

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    if (names.Any())
    {
        //select new { Id = id, Name = name };
    }
    else
    {
        //select new { Id = id, Name = "" }; // <-- Notice empty string
    }
}
```

**Answer to your question**

@BrianRogers has answered your question but I elaborated on what the issue is.